# How can I Count the Number of Rows of the JSON File?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My JSON file below contains six rows:

```
[
    {"events":[[{"v":"INPUT","n":"type"},{"v":"2016-08-24 14:23:12 EST","n":"est"}]],
     "apps":[],
     "agent":{"calls":[],"info":[{"v":"7990994","n":"agentid"},{"v":"7999994","n":"stationid"}]},
     "header":[{"v":"TUSTX002LKVT1JN","n":"host"},{"v":"192.168.1.18","n":"ip"},{"v":"V740723","n":"vzid"},{"v":"16.3.16.0","n":"version"},{"v":"12","n":"cpu"},{"v":"154665","n":"seq"},{"v":"2016-08-24 14:23:17 EST","n":"est"}]
    },
{"events":[[{"v":"INPUT","n":"type"},{"v":"2016-08-24 14:23:14 EST","n":"est"}]],"apps":[],"agent":{"calls":[],"info":[{"v":"7990994","n":"agentid"},{"v":"7999994","n":"stationid"}]},"header":[{"v":"TUSTX002LKVT1JN","n":"host"},{"v":"192.168.1.18","n":"ip"},{"v":"V740723","n":"vzid"},{"v":"16.3.16.0","n":"version"},{"v":"5","n":"cpu"},{"v":"154666","n":"seq"},{"v":"2016-08-24 14:23:23 EST","n":"est"}]},
{"events":[[{"v":"LOGOFF","n":"type"},{"v":"2016-08-24 14:24:04 EST","n":"est"}]],"apps":[],"agent":{"calls":[],"info":[{"v":"7990994","n":"agentid"},{"v":"7999994","n":"stationid"}]},"header":[{"v":"TUSTX002LKVT1JN","n":"host"},{"v":"192.168.1.18","n":"ip"},{"v":"V740723","n":"vzid"},{"v":"16.3.16.0","n":"version"},{"v":"0","n":"cpu"},{"v":"154667","n":"seq"},{"v":"2016-08-24 14:24:05 EST","n":"est"}]},
{"events":[],"apps":[[{"v":"ccSvcHst","n":"pname"},{"v":"7704","n":"pid"},{"v":"Old Virus Definition File","n":"title"},{"v":"O","n":"state"},{"v":"5376","n":"mem"},{"v":"0","n":"cpu"}]],"agent":{"calls":[],"info":[{"v":"7990994","n":"agentid"},{"v":"7999994","n":"stationid"}]},"header":[{"v":"TUSTX002LKVT1JN","n":"host"},{"v":"192.168.0.5","n":"ip"},{"v":"V740723","n":"vzid"},{"v":"16.3.16.0","n":"version"},{"v":"29","n":"cpu"},{"v":"154668","n":"seq"},{"v":"2016-09-25 16:57:24 EST","n":"est"}]},
{"events":[],"apps":[[{"v":"ccSvcHst","n":"pname"},{"v":"7704","n":"pid"},{"v":"Old Virus Definition File","n":"title"},{"v":"F","n":"state"},{"v":"5588","n":"mem"},{"v":"0","n":"cpu"}]],"agent":{"calls":[],"info":[{"v":"7990994","n":"agentid"},{"v":"7999994","n":"stationid"}]},"header":[{"v":"TUSTX002LKVT1JN","n":"host"},{"v":"192.168.0.5","n":"ip"},{"v":"V740723","n":"vzid"},{"v":"16.3.16.0","n":"version"},{"v":"16","n":"cpu"},{"v":"154669","n":"seq"},{"v":"2016-09-25 16:57:30 EST","n":"est"}]},
{"events":[],"apps":[[{"v":"ccSvcHst","n":"pname"},{"v":"7704","n":"pid"},{"v":"Old Virus Definition File","n":"title"},{"v":"F","n":"state"},{"v":"5588","n":"mem"},{"v":"0","n":"cpu"}]],"agent":{"calls":[],"info":[{"v":"7990994","n":"agentid"},{"v":"7999994","n":"stationid"}]},"header":[{"v":"TUSTX002LKVT1JN","n":"host"},{"v":"192.168.0.5","n":"ip"},{"v":"V740723","n":"vzid"},{"v":"16.3.16.0","n":"version"},{"v":"17","n":"cpu"},{"v":"154670","n":"seq"},{"v":"2016-09-25 16:57:36 EST","n":"est"}]}
]
```

The JSON looks like the below records:

```
JSON
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

Required Output:

```
Count
6
```

Comment: Can you please somewhat format your JSON and provide some code showing how you've tried solving the problem?

Comment: Hi Dennis i am unable to paste the  formatted Json Here ,please paste the Json in the http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ .you will get formatted JSON and please let me know your suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you are in Spark, and you need to turn your Json into dataset, and use the appropriate operation on it. So here, I wrote the workflow to go from Json to dataset in general and the required steps with examples. I think this way of answering is more beneficial because you can see the steps and then you can decide what to do with the information.

1. **Input Data**: You have the Json, that is your data you should start working on. Then you need to decide which fields are important. Counting on its own, is the small part of most cases and you don't want to load all the fields which may not be necessary.
2. **Create a Case Class**: you can use case classes because then you can serialize your input data. To keep it simple I have a doctor which belongs to a department, and I get the data in Json. I could have the following case classes:

   ```
   case class Department(name: String, address: String)
   case class Doctor(name: String, department: Department)
   ```

   so as you can see from the above code, I go bottom up to create the data I want to work on. In you Json, there are loads of fields (e.g., `v`) that I can't understand the meaning behind it. So be careful not to mix them.
3. **Have a dataaset**: Ok, the below code serialize a Json to the case class we defined:

   ```
   spark.read.json("doctorsData.json).as[Doctor]
   ```

   couple of points. The `spark` is a spark session, which you need to create. Here its instance is `spark` it could be anything. You also need to `import spark.implicits._`.
4. **In Business!**: Ok now you are in business, and in the Spark world. It is just the matter of using `count()` to count your dataset. THe following method shows how to count it:

   ```
   def recordsCount(myDataset: Dataset[Doctor]): Long = myDataset.count()
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A file of three records I have - with correct formatting, Spark 2.x., reading into a dataframe / dataset:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.read
        .option("multiLine", true)
        .option("mode", "PERMISSIVE")
        .option("inferSchema", true)
        .json("/FileStore/tables/json_01.txt")

df.select("*").show(false)
df.printSchema()
df.count()
```

If just a total tally count, then this will suffice, last line.

```
res15: Long = 3
```